# Sending SMS with Twilio Trial account fail

Tags: c#, twilio

I am getting the error:

> The From phone number is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number
>   or short code for your account.

```
       // Send a new outgoing SMS by POSTing to the Messages resource
       MessageResource.Create(
                from: new PhoneNumber(fromPhoneNumber), 
                to: new PhoneNumber(personPhoneNumber), 
                body: $"Hey!");
```

I have entered 2 phone numbers in [verified calls](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/verified). One used for "from" and one used for "to".

How can I get a valid trial "from" phone number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still send an SMS using the Trial Account. But, Using Trial Accounts, You can send messages to only verified Numbers(Receiver Numbers) with that trial account. So, Please make sure have you verified receiver phone number before sending your message to them using the Trial Account. FYI, For the Paid Accounts you don't need to verify numbers(Receiver Numbers) before sending messages to them.

Hope this may help you to move forward!

Comment: Currently, I am getting an error for the "from" not for the "to".

Comment: "From Number" should be generated a number in Twilio for each Trial account. You can not use the verified number as "From Number". "Verified Numbers" are only for To Numbers for Trial Account

Comment: Oh really, where can I see it. I didn't get any such number AFAIK.

Comment: Login to Twilio -> in console page, All Products & Service Icon at left corner Top under console menu -> under SUPER NETWORK section -> clicks on #Phone Numbers option, you will redirect to that page where you can buy a new number for messaging and calling...

Comment: So you mean that I need to purchase a Twilio number in order to use the trial account for sending an SMS from my C# application, right?

Comment: Yes, correct. you have to purchase a number in order to use as a "from the number" for sending a message using trail account. I believe it will be taken up from your credited balance in the trial account and it won't cost you.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

In order to send SMS messages from Twilio, you need to buy a Twilio number. [You cannot send messages from your own number, even if it is verified in your account](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133967-Changing-the-sender-ID-for-sending-SMS-messages). As part of a trial account, you can only send to numbers that you have verified.

You can get one free number while on your trial account to test this out.

Comment: Great, so how can I get this one free number? I can't find it.

Comment: Head on over to the [phone numbers dashboard](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming) and pick up a number.